# PhantomJS + jQuery -> Can't get image

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, phantomjs

**PROBLEM:** the function inside `page.evaluate` doesn't find any `img` (therefore, `console.log(images.length)` outputs 0); however, there are many images in the page, and some even have ids.

**QUESTION:** What's going on? Why `$('img')` doesn't find anything?

**UPDATE 1:** This is a `<frame>` problem. I had to switch to the frame in order to make the jQuery script correctly work.

**DETAILS:** I'm running a phantomjs script to access a webpage ([link](http://www.receita.fazenda.gov.br/pessoajuridica/cnpj/cnpjreva/cnpjreva_solicitacao.asp)) and fetch all available images. It first saves a screenshot of the page just for comparison, and then it should through every `<img>` tag (using jQuery `$('img')`) and get the image dimensions and, using phantomjs's `page.clipRect`, it saves each image inside a folder.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var url = 'http://www.receita.fazenda.gov.br/pessoajuridica/cnpj/cnpjreva/cnpjreva_solicitacao.asp';

page.open(url, function (status) {

    console.log("Status: " + status);
            if (status === "success") {
        page.render('example.png');
    }

    // Asynchronous call!
    page.includeJs('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js', function () {

        console.log('\n Evaluate Page \n');
        // Sandboxed
        var images = page.evaluate(function () {
            var images = [];
            function getImgDimensions($i) {
                return {
                    top: $i.offset().top,
                    left: $i.offset().left,
                    width: $i.width(),
                    height: $i.height(),
                }
            }
            $('img').each(function () {
                var img = getImgDimensions($(this));
                images.push(img);
            });

            return images;
        });
        console.log(images.length);


        images.forEach(function (imageObj, index, array) {
            page.clipRect = imageObj;
            page.render('images/' + index + '.png');
        });

        // Exit the session
        phantom.exit();
    });
});
```

Comment: What PhantomJS version are you using? Please register to the [`onConsoleMessage`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-console-message.html), [`onError`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-error.html), [`onResourceError`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-error.html), [`onResourceTimeout`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-timeout.html) events. Maybe there are errors.

Comment: Please disregard the jsbin link above as it is not working. Consider the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yr1zyfL1/

Comment: Note that `page` is only accessible outside of the page context. So, you cannot register the event handlers inside of it. You can delete comments. For the future: all information should be in the question itself. Anything that might help you get an answer. If you've mentioned that the page contains an iframe, this would have been answered much faster. It is also a good idea to add the markup of the page to the question. If you would have done that, you might have noticed that there is an iframe and either solved it yourself or provided the markup including the iframe.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I didn't know that an `iframe` had to be treated this way, nor had I realized that the images were inside one. Thanks for taking the time to help me! What is a good way to add the markup of a page?

Comment: The same way you add code, but keep in mind that only those elements that you are interested in should be added including one or two parents. You're right, if you don't know that iframes are special, it is hard to find out. In this case a markup snippet wouldn't have been very helpful. Depending on the actual markup, you may try to provide more parents if for example the children don't have many interesting nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've looked at the site. The img that you want is inside of an iframe. You first need to switch to it.

Use for example:

```
page.switchToChildFrame(0);
```

to switch to the first child frame. Do this before you call `page.includeJs()`.

If you want to do something in the parent page afterwards, you would have to change back with `page.switchToParentFrame();`.

Comment: Or just link to the frame directly `http://www.receita.fazenda.gov.br/pessoajuridica/cnpj/cnpjreva/cnpjreva_solicitacao2.asp` But also note the image is loaded asynchronously so you'll have to wait for it.

Comment: The solution works nicely. Using `page.switchToChildFrame(1)` (instead of `0`) I can finally get the `#imgCaptcha` and the correct width and height. However, the offset (`top` and `left`) are in relation to the frame itself (or something like that), so that when I use `page.clipRect` I end up getting a .png of some texts a little bit above the Captcha.

Comment: @GuilhermeSalomé I didn't account for that. Maybe you can provide your final code as a separate answer?

Comment: @ArtjomB. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28508496/finding-the-offset-of-a-frame-phantomjs-jquery